# How to detect if docker run succeeded programmatically?

Tags: bash, docker

I'm writing a very simple bash script to quickly check that my container still builds and starts correctly and that the app inside responds to requests.

Sometimes `docker run` fails, e.g. because the port I'm trying to bind the container to is already allocated. But when this happens `docker run`'s exit code is still 0 so I can't use the exit code. How can I check programmatically that the container got started correctly?

The solutions I'm considering are:

- parse the output for errors
- `docker ps` to see if the container is running

but these both seem a little overkill and ugly. Am I missing a better way to check whether `docker run` succeeded?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem here.  If the process in question behaves the usual way then you could simply check for the exit code.  If it emits an exit code of 0 even for failed cases, try to figure if it's a bug.  If the program returns an exit code of 0 in whatever case, then you're probably left with no choice but to parse the output.

Comment: As @devnull said, if you can't trust that `docker run` will return a non-zero return code on failure as you indicate then all you can do is parse the output (which might be complicated or fragile) or use another command (i.e. your `ps` suggestion) to check the result of the first command. You might want to consider filing a ticket with docker to see if they can fix the return code from `run` also.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version.

Comment: Is it custom code that being ran in your container? if so, you can export a port in your Dockerfile, when your program is in a stable running state send an "OK" message on that port. Your client code waits for the "OK" message.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you are running docker and which version? A quick test shows docker exit code to be 1 for me `docker run -d -p 9010:9010 busybox true ; echo $?`

Comment: Ah interesting, the same test for me still gives 0. I am running version 0.9.1 of docker (both client and server), maybe this has been fixed in v1? Unfortunately I can't upgrade right now, but I found another workaround that works decently that I'll put as an answer if someone else hits this.

Comment: is there a solution within python?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

As suggested by Abel Muiño in comments, this may have been fixed in more recent Docker versions (I'm currently running 0.9.1).

But, if you're temporarily stuck like me with an older version, I did find a decent workaround to check if the container started by using `docker inspect`.

`docker inspect` returns a JSON object with a lot of info about the container, and in particular whether the container is currently running or not. The `-f` flag lets you easily extract the bits needed:

```
docker inspect -f {{.State.Running}} $CONTAINER_ID
```

or

```
docker inspect -f "{{.State.Running}}" $CONTAINER_ID
```

will return `true` or `false`.

Note that you probably want to `sleep 1` (or more) between starting the container and checking if it is up. If there's something wrong with your setup it's possible that it would appear as 'running' for a very short time before actually exiting.

Comment: Why not use `docker inspect -f {{.State.Running}} <container-id>` and use `jq` instead? Just wondering.

Comment: Because I hadn't realized inspect lets you do this directly! Thanks @DharmitShah that's a great suggestion, I'll update my answer.

Comment: To suppress the error message if there is no such container, redirect stderr with `2> /dev/null`.

Comment: If I am assigning this to a var, i get an error when using `2> /dev/null` since it doesn't evaluate to anything. How can I make it default to `false` if the container doesn't exist?

Comment: This doesn't however accommodate containers that are constantly restarting because of the restart policy...
I.e. if a container is given a restart policy of unless-stopped/always, .State.Running will always return true....
Just something to be weary of!

Comment: is there a solution within python?

Comment: BTW, do not use the exit status of the command. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77296259/20307768

Answer (score 21):

To avoid parsing anything, you could use *docker top*, which returns 1 if the container is not running:

```
id=$(docker run mycontainer)
if ! docker top $id &>/dev/null
then
    echo "Container crashed unexpectedly..."
    return 1
fi
```

Answer (score 10):

We could use `docker exec $id true 2>/dev/null || echo not running`.

This command does not write to stdout, as "docker top" does. It writes to stderr when the container is not running, the same  message as "docker top".

Answer (score 2):

Applying the suggestions aforementioned to a script.

1 - Create a script **keepMyDockerUp.sh** :

```
vi keepMyDockerUp.sh


#!/bin/bash
Container_ID=INSERT_YOUR_CONTAINER_ID HERE
result=$( docker inspect -f {{.State.Running}} $Container_ID)
echo "result is" $result
if [ $result = "true" ]
then
echo "docker is already running"
else
systemctl restart docker
docker start $Container_ID
fi
```

2 - Then simply add it to cron, so your script verifies whether your Docker container is up from time to time:

```
crontab -e
```

Go to the last line and add your script file. For example:

```
* * * * * /root/keepMyDockerUp.sh
```

3 - Save crontab and never worry about your Docker container being down again.

Hope it helps...

;-)

Comment: This is really neat, but is it necessary? Doesn't it duplicate what the auto restart feature of docker run already does?

Answer (score 1):

I had to use:

```
$ docker inspect -f {{.State.Health.Status}} xxx
```

(the container was in state running but the service inside the container wasn't fully started.

Part of inspect output:

```
"State": {
    "Status": "running",
    "Running": true,
    "Paused": false,
    "Restarting": false,
    "OOMKilled": false,
    "Dead": false,
    "Pid": 1618,
    "ExitCode": 0,
    "Error": "",
    "StartedAt": "2019-03-08T10:39:24.061732398Z",
    "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "Health": {
        "Status": "starting",
        "FailingStreak": 0,
        "Log": []
```

Comment: This would not state if the run was successful. Because a container may run and then fail.

Answer (score 0):

To who is using **the exit status** of `docker inspect --format="{{.State.Running}}"` to test, **Don't**.

`docker inspect --format="{{.State.Running}}" $ALIVE_CONTAINER; echo $?`

`docker inspect --format="{{.State.Running}}" $DEAD_CONTAINER; echo $?`

**Both are ZERO. (Podman shows the same result.)**

I saw exit status 1 because `docker inspect --format="{{.State.Running}}" $NO_EXISTENT_NAME; echo $?`

**Rather do it like this**

like [Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/343944/546660)'s answer.

```
return=$(docker inspect --format="{{.State.Running}}" -q $CONTAINER)

#the $return is true string or false string
```

or
if you really want to use exit status,

```
docker inspect --format="{{.State.Running}}" $CONTAINER | grep 'true'
#or grep 'false'
# both GNU or BSD grep returns 0 as a exit status if the line was selected
# EXIT STATUS section of https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?grep
# https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html
```