# Docker Containers not running on boot2docker boot

Tags: windows, docker, virtual-machine, windows-10, boot2docker

Operating system: Windows10

Using:

- Oracle VM VirtualBox
- DockerToolbox v1.9.1i

Hi, do you know how to start a container automatically at boot2docker boot?

I have created a new machine with `docker-machine`. Then I have run a new container with `docker run`. It's all up and and running, but when I shutdown my Windows and try to start my *docker machine* the container inside doesn't start. I have tried to add `docker start id` command to the file `/mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` but it doesn't work.

I have tried also to connect to the virtual  machine with ssh (`docker-machine ssh name`) and run the command `docker start id` without success. Finally I have to stop and remove the container and make a `docker run` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your container don't start because when the machine (the boot2docker VM) restarts, it still has it in an '`Exited`' state.

Confirm with a `docker-machine ssh default "docker ps -a"`. (after a `docker-machine start default`)

If so, add in your `/mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` a call to a script which will:

- test [if the container is exited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24560463/6309):

  ```
  docker inspect -f {{.State.Running}} $CONTAINER_ID
  ```
- if the previous command

  - errors, it means the container is *not* runnig at all: `docker run`
  - returns false, `docker rm` + `docker run`
  - return true: nothing to do.